# problem in lunch uwp toast notification from appx folder

Tags: uwp, wns

I have uwp app toast notification by WNS service. My app work fine when lunch in visual studio but when i run app from appx folder toast notification does not display. I dont have any exception when toast notification.Excuse me for bad language.

```
private async void ToastNotification(NotificationModel notificationModel)
    {
        string title = notificationModel.Title;
        string content = notificationModel.Content;
        string image = notificationModel.ImageUrl;
        int conversationId = notificationModel.Id;
        ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent()
        {
            Visual = new ToastVisual()
            {
                BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new AdaptiveText()
                        {
                            Text = title
                        },
                        new AdaptiveText()
                        {
                            Text = content
                        },

                        new AdaptiveImage()
                        {
                            Source = await DownloadImageToDisk(image)
                        }
                    },
                    AppLogoOverride = new ToastGenericAppLogo()
                    {
                        Source = await DownloadImageToDisk(notificationModel.IconUrl),
                        HintCrop = ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle
                    }
                }
            },
            Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
            {
                Buttons =
                {
                    new ToastButton("view", new QueryString()
                    {
                        { "action", "GoToLink" },
                        { "link", notificationModel.LinkAddress }

                    }.ToString())
                }
            },
            ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background,
            Scenario = ToastScenario.Reminder
        };
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(toastContent.GetContent());
        var toast = new ToastNotification(doc);
        toast.Failed += (o, args) =>
        {
            var message = args.ErrorCode;
            MessageBox.Show(message.Message);
        };
        DesktopNotificationManagerCompat.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
        _beharaSqlDependency.NotificationIsSent(notificationModel.Id);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean that the application normally pops up notifications in debug state, but can't display notifications in Release mode (or after installing the application through the installation package)? Can you share the code of your display the notification, this helps us analyze your problem

Comment: Yes of course I didn't use the installer and just run app from appx folder in debug mode and release mode! just when run app lunch in visual studio work fine. i use [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop#step-10-deploying-and-debugging).

Comment: Hi, It is recommended that you first install the Desktop Bridge application through the installer, rather than running the program directly from the appx folder. The installer can provide the AUMID required for the pop-up notification. If you don't pop up the notification correctly, it is most likely that your app AUMID does not match the AUMID in the code

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT Hi, I install package by wix tool and work fine, thanks a lot